# Data frame creation inside Parlapply in R

Tags: r, dataframe, parallel-processing, doparallel

I am trying something pretty simple, want to run a bunch of regressions parallelly.  When I use the following data generator (PART 1), The parallel part does not work and give the error listed below

```
#PART 1
p <- 20; rho<-0.7;
cdc<- diag(p)
for( i in 1:(p-1) ){ for( j in (i+1):p ){
  cdc[i,j] <- cdc[j,i] <- rho^abs(i-j)
}}
my.data <- mvrnorm(n=100, mu = rep(0, p), Sigma = cdc)
```

The following Parallel Part does work but if I generate the data as PART 2

```
# PART 2
my.data<-matrix(rnorm(1000,0,1),nrow=100,ncol=10)
```

I configured the function that I want to run parallelly... as

```
parallel_fun<-function(obj,my.data){
  p1 <- nrow(cov(my.data));store.beta<-matrix(0,p1,length(obj))
  count<-1
  for (itration in obj) {
    my_df<-data.frame(my.data)
    colnames(my_df)[itration] <- "y"
    my.model<-bas.lm(y ~ ., data= my_df, alpha=3,
                     prior="ZS-null", force.heredity = FALSE, pivot = TRUE)
    cf<-coef(my.model, estimator="MPM") 
    betas<-cf$postmean[-1]
    store.beta[ -itration, count]<- betas
    count<-count+1
  }
  result<-list('Beta'=store.beta)
}
```

So I write the following way of running parlapply

```
{
  no_cores <- detectCores(logical = TRUE)  
  myclusternumber<-(no_cores-1)
  cl <- makeCluster(myclusternumber)  
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  p1 <- ncol(my.data)
  obj<-splitIndices(p1, myclusternumber) 
  clusterExport(cl,list('parallel_fun','my.data','obj'),envir=environment())
   clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    library(MASS)
    library(Matrix)
    library(BAS)
  })
  newresult<-parallel::parLapply(cl,obj,fun = parallel_fun,my.data)
  stopCluster(cl)
  
}
```

But whenever am doing PART 1 I get the following error

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
> 7 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'my_df' not found

But this should not happen, the data frame should be created, I have no idea why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the object created? Maybe instead you want to use ``data=my_df `` in that ``my.model`` call?

Comment: @runr well I edited the toy code.

Comment: Are you still getting the error after the edit? I'm able to replicate your code without issues. I'm not sure whether the result is as expected, but there are no errors regarding any object not found

Comment: Try running the example code in a fresh R instance. Run before all else ``rm(list = ls())`` in order to clean the environment, and see if you still are getting errors.

Comment: I am still getting errors 
`p <- 20; rho<-0.7;
cdc<- diag(p);
for( i in 1:(p-1) ){ for( j in (i+1):p ){
  cdc[i,j] <- cdc[j,i] <- rho^abs(i-j)
}}
my.data <- mvrnorm(n=100, mu = rep(0, p), Sigma = cdc)`
the error is back for this dataset

Comment: I'm getting them too now. It's weird, the issue is with ``BAS:::coef.bas`` call. I'll look into it

Comment: I was using `cf<-coefficients(bas.model, estimator="MPM")` This too gives errors. 
Furthermore I tried running this in a for loop. Instead `for (itration in obj) {`, I ran `for (itration in 1:p1) {` .... weirdly the for loop works!! not the parallel code!

Comment: Posted a "hack", see if it works. I'm not a fan of ``<<-`` assigns, there should be a simpler way through proper management of environments, but I'm not an expert there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as one possible workaround, see if it works:

```r
parallel_fun<-function(obj,my.data){
  p1 <- nrow(cov(my.data));store.beta<-matrix(0,p1,length(obj))
  count<-1
  for (itration in obj) {
    my_df<-data.frame(my.data)
    colnames(my_df)[itration] <- "y"
    my_df <<- my_df
    my.model<-bas.lm(y ~ ., data= my_df, alpha=3,
                     prior="ZS-null", force.heredity = FALSE, pivot = TRUE)
    cf<-BAS:::coef.bas(my.model, estimator="MPM") 
    betas<-cf$postmean[-1]
    store.beta[ -itration, count]<- betas
    count<-count+1
  }
  result<-list('Beta'=store.beta)
}
```

The issue seems to be with `BAS:::coef.bas` function, that calls `eval` in order to get `my_df` and fails to do that when called in parallel. The "hack" here is to  force `my_df` out to the parent environment by calling `my_df <<- my_df`.

There should be a better way to do this, but `<<-` might be the fastest one. In general, `<<-` may cause unwanted behaviour, especially when used in loops. Assigning unique variable name before exporting (and don't forgetting to remove after use) is one way to tackle them.